# "more than one device/emulator" ao tentar usar o celular no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Bom dia, comecei a estudar desenvolvimento de games para Android e senti a necessidade de usar o smartphone no lugar do emulador, configurei o adb, o mesmo reconheceu, porém nada aparece no avd.
o que pode estar errado?[
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente matar o emulador, ele parece estar se confundido pelo fato de haver 2 devices (um real e outro emulado)

Comment: Olá, Ronaldo. Por favor, evite de usar capturas de tela para ilustrar o erro. Imagens dificultam buscas futuras e atrapalham usuários de leitores de tela.

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado pela resposta, mesmo fazendo o procedimento, não funciona, quando abro o avd ele está vazio e pede para criar um novo virtual device.